# Checking geometry validity

Tags: geometry, qgis-3, validation

I'm using QGIS 3.0 and I have a problem with checking
validity of the geometries of a shapefile.

I imported a DXF, converted the polylines into polygons, manually corrected the wrong or intersecting polygons. Now I would like to cut out a raster using my building shapefile as a mask, but continue to
generate the message in figure 1:

[image]

I then made the topological check, then the geometric one, but nothing
seems to solve the error as seen in figure 2:

[image]

I'm almost thinking of doing all the polygons manually, but I would like to understand how to solve the problem in case I find myself developing projects with thousands of polygons in the future.

Comment: Maybe you could add new screenshots with your language set to english?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Clipper tool available in the raster menu instead? (see in Raster > Extraction > Clipper..)

What error message does the geometry validation tool returns?

Comment: HI Carlos ERROR1: Cutline feature without a geometry